# Multiple many_many relationships in Silverstripe

Tags: silverstripe

I'm just wondering if it is possible to have multiple many_many relationships on the same class. For example, I have a Table A, Table B and Table C. I want a many_many relationship between Table A and Table B and another many_many relationship between Table A and Table C. I have tried this but it is not adding the IDs to the tables it creates. I did some searching and found this http://www.balbuss.com/multiple-many-many-s-of-the-same-class/ and am not sure whether it is even possible now.

Any help is very much appreciated.

I had a thought about using onAfterWrite to populate the linked table but should I need to do this?

```
class Table B extends DateObject {
static $belongs_many_many = array (
    'TableAs' => 'TableA'
);
}

class Table C extends DateObject {
static $belongs_many_many = array (
    'TableAs' => 'TableA'
);
}

class Table A extends Page {
    static $many_many = array (
    'TableB' => 'TableB',
    'TableC' => 'TableC'
);
}
```

Comment: no, onAfterWrite doesn't sound like the right way to fix this.
could you add your current code please?

Comment: Thanks for the response on this @Zauberfisch.  I've added the code above which is the bit that relates to the many_many relationship.

Comment: the relations are certainly possible this way, I my self have many cases where my relations look just like yours.
So you are saying relations are not saved? Could you also post the code of how you save the relations? what are you using to manage the relations?

Comment: Ah that is where my confusion arises.  I am fairly new to this area of SilverStripe but should this not work similarly to the has_one relationship? I assumed (probably naively) that the IDs would be automatically added to the tables once I create a new Table B for example.  Is this not the case?

Comment: well, yes relations are auto saved, but only if you use the right tool for it.
For example a ManyManyComplexTableField or a ManyManyDataObjectManager in ss2 or the GridField in ss3 would save the relation

Comment: I see. I need the ManyManyDataObjectManager then?  I was using the plain old DataObjectManager.  That explains it.  If you post it as an answer I'll give you the credit.  Thanks.  One other thing though, if I wanted to iterate through each instance of TableA, for example, and create a row in the linked table with TableA's ID and TableB's ID would I need to use raw SQL with SilverStripe 2.4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for managing many_many relations in SilverStripe you can use to following field:

ss2.4: `ManyManyComplexTableField`or `ManyManyDataObjectManager`, both provide a list of all records of that type, and let you choose the relation with checkboxes

ss3.0: `GridField`, but you might have to add the checkboxes your self, not sure

also, in both 2.4 and 3.0 there are some dropdown fields and other field that support many_many relations as well (for example the `TreeMultiselectField`)

---

I am not sure what you mean with "iterate through each instance of TableA" in the comment, if you just want to loop all TableAs that are asigned to a single record of TableB then you can do:

```
foreach ($tableBrecord->TableAs($filter = "", $sort = "", $join = "", $limit = "") as $tableArecord) {
   // do something with $tableArecord
}
```

But if you really want to do something on ALL records of TableA then you can do:

```
foreach(DataObject::get('TableA', $filter = "", $sort = "", $join = "", $limit = "") as $tableArecord) {
   // do something with $tableArecord
}
```

if you have a LOT of TableA records this might be a little slow, so you could also do a native query like so

```
 DB::query('UPDATE TableA SET ...');
```

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clearer @Zauberfisch.  The second option seems to be the one I want.  I was trying something like this. $Tables = DataObject::get("TableA") as this line worked before.  I want to add the ID from each store to the linked table along with the newly created Table B's ID.

Comment: have you figured it out? I am not sure if your comment is a statement or a question :)

Comment: No what I've been trying hasn't worked.  I apologise for this drawn out question.  I'll keep at it.  Thanks for your help and your patience. :)

Comment: If you still need help for it, please raise a new question, and post code to it, I am still not sure what you actually want to do and what happens instead